# Expand div to fit floated children instead of inserting line breaks

Tags: html, css

Consider this simple example

```
<div class="outer">
     <div class="left">
          left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left 
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to `float` the children `div`s to left and right, in the same line. Also, when the outer `div`size is shrinked, I want it to scroll, rather than inserting a line break between the 2 divs.

This is my CSS:

```
.outer {
    width:fit-content;
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
.left, .right{
    display:inline-block;
}

.left {
    background-color: #dcc2c2;
}
.right {
    clear:none;
    float:right;
    background-color: #d0dee8;
}
```

The problem is that when outer `div` is shrinked, a line break is inserted:
[image]

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Bqvg/12/). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `width:fit-contents;` new? I'm not familiar with it. Ah, it should be `width:fit-content;` and it's experimental.

Comment: I guess fit-content is a thing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) learned something new!

Comment: Apparently it is. (`width:fit-content` the `s` is a typo). see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes):

```css
.outer {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Flush to the edges */
  overflow-x: auto; /* Add scrollbar if necessary */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left, .right {
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Don't shrink them */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Don't wrap lines inside them */
}
.left {
  background-color: #dcc2c2;
}
.right {
  background-color: #d0dee8;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### Table it

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left,
.right {
  display: table-cell;
}
.left {
  background-color: #dcc2c2;
}
.right {
  background-color: #d0dee8;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `table` is a good solution if I control `width`. In my case I can't.

Comment: @ahmohamed You don't have to define the width. If you play with the above example by removing the width, you'll see that the table just shrinks to the width of the content.

Comment: FWIW I like the table solution because of its simplicity and cross-browser support (including legacy browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Use `absolute` position of both `left` and `right` divs and `relative` position of `outer`

```
.outer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    ...
}
.left, .right{
    display:inline-block;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

But `outer`'s height should be set implicitly.

http://jsfiddle.net/4Bqvg/13/

Answer (score 0):

You need to float your .left class, you aren't doing that.

```
.left {
    background-color: #dcc2c2;
    float: left;
}
```

This will make .left and .right float in the same line, until there isn't enough room on that line, then they fill below.

You should also set the height of the .outer div.

Answer (score 0):

On browsers that support [`text-align-last`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last), you can display them as inline-blocks and justify them:

```css
.outer {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -moz-text-align-last: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
}
.left {
  background-color: #dcc2c2;
}
.right {
  background-color: #d0dee8;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left">left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```